# What happens when you escape numbers?

Tags: javascript, php, html, string, numbers

I have this code that replaces match of a `REGEX` capture group with a `back-reference`, but the matched text was always replaced with nothing i.e. cut of.

**The code:**

```
$str = 'string is string';
$replacement_result = preg_replace("/(\w+) is (\w+)/","\1 this \3", $str);

echo $replacement_result;
// results was 'is'
```

I then noticed that the replacement parameter string was in double quote and was escaping the number(which i thought would work fine), so I changed the double quotes to single quotes

```
$str = 'string is string';
                                                     // changes here
$replacement_result = preg_replace("/(\w+) is (\w+)/",'\1 this \3', $str);

echo $replacement_result;
// results was 'string this string'
```

I even tried `document.write()` ing and escaped number in `Javascript` and 'twas the same result (nothing).

So obviously this is my first encounter with this, and there is a very simple 1 - 2 line answer.
What happens when a number is escaped?

Comment: In PHP, `"\1"` is an octal character notation, `'\1'` is a backreference. When your first code snippet is run, the result is not `is`, but `\u0001 this \u0002`

Comment: Yeah you're right a made a mistake with the first result, Thanks for you response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), within a double-quoted string, a sequence of backslash followed by `1..3` digits in range `0..7` is interpreted as a character in octal notation:

> `\[0-7]{1,3}`     the sequence of characters matching the regular
>   expression is a character in octal notation, which silently overflows
>   to fit in a byte (e.g. `"\400" === "\000"`)

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, stackoverflow says i can't accept an answer within 2mins.